# Dataframe has no column names. How to add a header?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a dataset to practice for building a decision tree classifier.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
tdf = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', sep = ',', header=0)
tdf.info()
```

The column has no name, and i have problem to add the column name, already tried reindex, pd.melt, rename, etc.

The column names Ι want to assign are:

1. Sample code number: id number
2. Clump Thickness: 1 - 10
3. Uniformity of Cell Size: 1 - 10
4. Uniformity of Cell Shape: 1 - 10
5. Marginal Adhesion: 1 - 10
6. Single Epithelial Cell Size: 1 - 10
7. Bare Nuclei: 1 - 10
8. Bland Chromatin: 1 - 10
9. Normal Nucleoli: 1 - 10
10. Mitoses: 1 - 10
11. Class: (2 for benign, 4 for malignant)

Thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For any dataframe, say df , you can add/modify column names by passing the column names in a list to the df.columns method:
For example, if you want the column names to be 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],use this:

`df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

In your code , can you remove `header=0`? This basically tells pandas to take the first row as the column headers . Once you remove that, use the above to assign the column names.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Tried this, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you remove header = 0 ? This argument basically tells pandas to take the first row as header .

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I am learning both DS and Python at the same time, it is really challenging. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Quick follow up:

Comment: Keep learning. Soon those efforts will pay off

Comment: If it worked , please accept and upvote the answer so others can benefit from it as well . Happy learning :)

Comment: i have a follow up question:

Comment: Hi, I tried the code above and you are missing the first line of data. I added a new answer which gets all the rows @GyanRanjan

Answer (score 11):

```
df = pd.read_csv("Price Data.csv", names=['Date', 'Price'])
```

use the `names` field to add a header to your pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried the code above and you are missing the first line of data.**

**1. original**

```
tdf = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', sep = ',', header=0)
tdf.shape
```

(698, 11)

**2. as the previous questions, removing header=0**

```
tdf = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', sep = ',')
tdf.shape
```

(698, 11)

**3. new answer, adding column names while reading csv, does get all the rows**

```
 tdf = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', sep = ',', names=['Sample code number: id number','Clump Thickness: 1 - 10','Uniformity of Cell Size: 1 - 10','Uniformity of Cell Shape: 1 - 10','Marginal Adhesion: 1 - 10','Single Epithelial Cell Size: 1 - 10','Bare Nuclei: 1 - 10','Bland Chromatin: 1 - 10','Normal Nucleoli: 1 - 10','Mitoses: 1 - 10','Class: (2 for benign, 4 for malignant)'])  
    tdf.shape
```

(**699**, 11)

You can assign the names of the columns when reading the csv file

```
import pandas as pd 
tdf = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', sep = ',', names=['Sample code number: id number','Clump Thickness: 1 - 10','Uniformity of Cell Size: 1 - 10','Uniformity of Cell Shape: 1 - 10','Marginal Adhesion: 1 - 10','Single Epithelial Cell Size: 1 - 10','Bare Nuclei: 1 - 10','Bland Chromatin: 1 - 10','Normal Nucleoli: 1 - 10','Mitoses: 1 - 10','Class: (2 for benign, 4 for malignant)'])
```

You can check the dataframe using

```
tdf.head()
```

and you get

[image]

You can check the code on https://gist.github.com/e94b31914dbaebda7d11f6bfe0cfbdec